# Where should a question about a web app / desktop client / API in combination go?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about Dropbox which involves the Desktop client, the web interface and the REST API.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60055/how-do-i-delete-lots-10-000-of-files-on-dropbox?noredirect=1#comment48094_60055

It was rejected from Super User, and from Web Apps.

https://superuser.com/posts/747177/revisions

Where should it go?

I also wrote an answer, which expresses information it took me a day to find out. This answer is no longer visible, which is really annoying, and discouraging me from contributing to Stack Exchange ever again. I'd really like others to find the answer too!

In this discussion, as well as answering the immediate question, suggestions as to how StackExchange should be improved so as not to annoy contributors like me in this case, would be welcome.

Comment: The answer is still visible at http://superuser.com/questions/747177/how-do-i-delete-lots-10-000-of-files-on-dropbox but it's not clear why the answer didn't migrate - is this a bug? [Disclaimer: I am 2 meters to the left of frabcus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question should not have been migrated from Super User as it was about using the desktop client - which should be on topic there.

People do get migrations wrong - and it's not helped by the fact that Dropbox is both a desktop application and web application.

As to the visibility of your answer. It's still visible on Super User. It did get migrated to Web Apps with the question, but when the migration was rejected it was deleted. This is the standard behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! As a user who this hasn't happened to before, the messaging was very offputting. This will be non-obvious to anyone who knows how it works, and I don't want to see StackExchange going the way of Wikipedia as a result. I'm not sure where to report the messaging should be better..